# Issues When Installing Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mamba

I was trying to install openpyxl and I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\anaconda3\Scripts\mamba-script.py", line 10, in 
> sys.exit(main())
> File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mamba\mamba.py", line 848, in main
> from conda.common.compat import ensure_text_type, init_std_stream_encoding
> ImportError: cannot import name 'init_std_stream_encoding' from 'conda.common.compat' (C:\Users\XXXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\compat.py

Can someone assist me on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73314769/10693596), based on [an answer/solution by @szymonos](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1370#issuecomment-1060052607):

> So I was installing mamba from conda-forge channel using command: `conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba`, but on the other hand, I had a script for updating conda environment using `mamba update --all`, but it was using the default channel and after that, mamba became corrupted with `AttributeError: module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'QueryFormat'`.
> Changing update command to `mamba update -c conda-forge -all` fixed the issue.