# Unable to install snakemake via conda

Tags: conda, mamba

I am trying to install snakemake as instructed by the tutorial:

```
conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba
conda activate base
mamba create -c conda-forge -c bioconda -n snakemake snakemake
```

But after the third line I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kusers/ancillary/mradzieta/anaconda3/bin/mamba", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/kusers/ancillary/mradzieta/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 848, in main
    from conda.common.compat import ensure_text_type, init_std_stream_encoding
ImportError: cannot import name 'init_std_stream_encoding' from 'conda.common.compat' (/kusers/ancillary/mradzieta/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/compat.py)
```

Comment: This is not a snakemake error, your `mamba/conda` setup is somehow messed up, so I am removing the snakemake tag

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread with [an answer/solution by @szymonos](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1370#issuecomment-1060052607):

> So I was installing mamba from conda-forge channel using command: `conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba`, but on the other hand, I had a script for updating conda environment using `mamba update --all`, but it was using the default channel and after that, mamba became corrupted with `AttributeError: module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'QueryFormat'`.
> Changing update command to `mamba update -c conda-forge -all` fixed the issue.

So based on the above, here's the sequence I would run:

```bash
conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba
# if the mamba got corrupted, can try: conda update --force-reinstall
conda activate base
mambe update -c conda-forge --all
mamba create -c conda-forge -c bioconda -n snakemake snakemake
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you try changing the order (and priority) of channels? `-c bioconda -c conda-forge`?

Comment: The above works on my machine (MacOS). Is there anything special about your setup?

Comment: Changing the order I get the same error. I don't think so I am just trying to install on a linux server.